# Modifying TCC.db on MacOS Mojave

Tags: macos, c++11, applescript, macos-mojave

I am working on MacOS application which needs to get name of active window. Application is written in Qt/C++. To get the active window and the name of it I am using AppleScript. Is this the best way to achieve this?

On MacOS Mojave I have been read that I need to modify TCC.db file to add my application so no dialog would appear asking for confirmation to the user. Is modifying tcc.db enough to whitelist my application or do I need to create some kind of Policy Control profile?

Finally, could someone tell me how to access tcc.db and modify it?

Thanks in advance and Regards

Comment: Bypassing the user's consent is not something you should be trying to do.

Comment: related (somehow): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53278712/home-folders-access-in-mojave-really-needs-full-disk-access